# (Maple) What is meant by "_the general term_" of an infinite series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, maple

I'm trying to finish off my assignment (which is due tomorrow), and the last question asks me to do the following on *Maple*.

> Write a **procedure** in Maple which calculates, in floating point form, the *general term* of the infinite series:
>
> $$2 \space+\space 2.3x \space+\space 3.4x^2 \space+\space 4.5x^3 \space+\space ...$$

I have no problem finding the $n^{th}$ term of the series using Maple, or finding the sum of the series for some $x$ using Maple.

My problem is that "*general term*" used in the question.

Is it asking me to make a procedure that finds a term in the sum?

OR

Does it want me to write a procedure for the sum of the series for some $x$?

Comment: They want you to find the $n$th term in the series!

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal Ahh that makes much more sense. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a series of the form $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k x^k ~=~ a_0 x^0+a_1 x^1+a_2+\ldots + a_k+\ldots$ .

The term $a_k$ is the general term of the series.   It is an expression for the $k$-th $0$-indexed term of the sequence, where $k$ is an arbitrary non-negative integer.   $k\in\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$

In this case you are looking for the term $a_k x^k$ in the series $2+2.3x+3.4x^2+4.5x^3+\ldots$